# What is the difference between queryPurchases vs queryinventory

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-billing

What is the difference between

queryPurchases vs queryinventory in in-app biling version 3?

When to use which?

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking about **IabHelper** class then

*queryInventory*:

> ```
>    Queries the inventory. This will query all owned items from the server, as well as
>    information on additional skus, if specified. This method may block or take long to execute.
> ```

And inside this method is invoked *queryPurchases* method, which verifying if purchase is legal and then return IABHELPER_VERIFICATION_FAILED or BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK codes. Also it add purchases in inventory.

BTW, *queryPurchases* is package-local method - you shouldn't use it.

Comment: The part that is confusing me is: Is this the inventory of what the user owns or all the available purchases that a user can buy or has bought?